# Delete trailing whitespace when saving, except certain modes

Tags: hooks, whitespace

How can I `delete-trailing-whitespace` when saving, except for certain modes? With this attempt, whitespace is deleted for all modes, including `fundamental-mode`, which I'm trying to avoid.

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
             (when '(not fundamental-mode))
               'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          (when '(not fundamental-mode))
             'delete-trailing-whitespace)
```

You are not passing a *function* as the second arg to `add-hook`.  You are passing the *symbol* `delete-trailing-whitespace`, systematically.

`add-hook` is a function, so all of its args are evaluated before it does its thing (using their values).  The value of the sexp you passed as its second arg is the symbol `delete-trailing-whitespace`, because the arg to `when` is a non-nil list (because you quoted it).  So the `when` condition is always true.

And you never invoke function `delete-trailing-whitespace`; you just return the symbol that names that function.

You need to pass a function to `add-hook`.  Something like this:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
              (delete-trailing-whitespace))))
```

But are you sure that you want to do that for every possible mode other than `fundamental-mode`?  If not, consider checking `major-mode` against a whitelist or a blacklist of modes.

And consider using `derived-mode-p` to test modes - it is typically more appropriate than testing them using `eq`.

Comment: Very good answer! I realise I really must sit down some day and try to learn the fascinating relic of another realm that is (Emacs) Lisp. Another user mentioned something about `derived-mode-p` not being straight-forward to use. Do you have an example of how you would set it up? (I do think I would like to use `delete-trailing-whitespace` for almost all files, except a certain file type which I've set to `fundamental-mode`).

Comment: `(defun diredp-hide-details-if-dired ()

    "In Dired mode hide details.  Outside Dired, do nothing."

    (when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode) (dired-hide-details-mode 1)))`

The point is that `eq` a mode does not allow for very similar modes that are just derived from that mode. In most cases, you want `derived-mode-p`, to treat derived modes the same way as the mode they're derived from.

Comment: OK, this deletes whitespace while in `hexl-mode` which is *definitely* not desirable. How do I turn this off? `(unless (eq major-mode '(fundamental-mode hexl-mode))` did not work.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read a bit in the Intro to Emacs Lisp manual (`C-h i`. You are trying to test equality (`eq`) between a symbol (the value of `major-mode` and a list (`(fundamental-mode hexl-mode)`).